# else if condition not executing statement

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, sprite-kit

I am building a gameOver scene where if you reach a certain amount of Points you either get 1, 2 or 3 Stars.

I wrote a if Condition block that looks like this:

```
var starImage = SKSpriteNode()
    if gameScore > 500 {
        starImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "2_stars")
        print("You achieved 2 Stars")
    } else if gameScore > 1000 {
        starImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "3_stars")
        print("You achieved 3 Stars")
    } else {
        starImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "1_star")
        print("You achieved 1 Star")
    }
    starImage.setScale(2)
    starImage.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height * 0.9)
    starImage.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(starImage)
```

2_stars and 1_star work fine, but the else if condition doesn't seem to execute.

However the weird thing is, when I replace the greater than (>) symbols with equals (==) all 3 conditions work.

I did try using >= but that has the same effect as >.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. Your `else if` statement can only evaluate to true in case your initial `if` statement evaluates to true, but since you used an `else if`, the two can never execute at the same time.

You should simply change the conditions of the `if` and `else if` branches to make it work.

```
if gameScore > 1000 {
    starImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "3_stars")
    print("You achieved 3 Stars")
} else if gameScore > 500 {
    starImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "2_stars")
    print("You achieved 2 Stars")
} else {
    starImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "1_star")
    print("You achieved 1 Star")
}
```

Comment: That worked, I do have another issue with a if statement where I wanna change the color of a textLabel to red if the livesNumber goes to 1, but that if statement isn't working at all. Any idea what that would happen?

if livesNumber == 1 {
        livesLabel.fontColor = SKColor.red
        } else {
            livesLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
        }

Comment: @snapbackdev you should post another question regarding that, since without more context it's quite hard to tell what might be going wrong there

Comment: I would but I can only post every 90 minutes :-D I'll post it tomorrow, thanks for the help worked like a charm

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `switch` to ensure this can never happen:

```
let starCount: Int
switch gameScore {
    case ...500:       starCount = 1
    case 501 ..< 1000: starCount = 2
    case 1001...:      starCount = 3
}
let sOrBlank = (starCount) == 1 ? "" : "s"
starImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "\(starCount)_star\(sOrBlank)")
print("You achieved \(starCount) Star\(sOrBlank)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `else if` condition is never checked because the score will always be greater than 500 even if it is 1250. Hence, only 2 stars are given out.

Change initial if to check if score is greater than 500 and less than 1000.